# wkhtmltoimage Occasionally Freezes

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**
1. Install/compile using scripts/static-build.sh, using "linux-local"
2. Run something like: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage "http://www.rawartists.org/scripts/event-flyer.php?url=http://www.rawartists.org/philadelphia/menagerie&image=true" test.jpg

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**
Rendering is supposed to be completed, but instead it stalls at about the 80-85% range of rendering every so often. There is no clear, discernible pattern to when it will complete rendering or not. (See screenshot for where rendering stops.)

**What version of wkhtmltopdf are you using?**
0.10.0 rc2

**On what operating system?**
Linux Ubuntu server 10.4

**Please provide any additional information below.**

I'm not sure if it's because I'm using 0.10 or because I get the occasional "QHttpNetworkConnectionChannel::_q_receiveReply() called without QHttpNetworkReply, 0 bytes on socket." message in the output (which happens when it does and does not work).

[image: Freeze image generating]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you running a one threaded server?

Comment: Get the same anomaly with 0.11.0 rc

Comment: Seems to be the same : http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=888 http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=1055

Comment: It looks like the error comes from QT https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9315